# What is a good workaround for "sort" command's limitation to 65535 characters per line?

Tags: shell, sorting, command-line, cmd, unix

Here is a snippet from Sort command's help functionality:

```
 /REC[ORD_MAXIMUM] characters Specifies the maximum number of characters
                         in a record (default 4096, maximum 65535).
```

Here is the error when I try to sort a file with long lines:

```
C:\Users\heqin\PIM2>cat Artist_Input.tsv | sort /REC 65535
Input record exceeds maximum length.  Specify larger maximum.
```

Short of writing a custom script (in Python, for example) just to handle this case, what is a good workaround to sorting files with lines longer than 65535?

As a clarification, I am using the Unix Utils version of "sort", running on Windows.

Comment: is this a theoretical question, or do you really have lines of data -gt 65535? If so, there are commercial sort products that may handle large line sizes OR you can always get the source and compile with a large Max value. Oh wait, you're on windows, that may not work. Good luck!

Comment: I really have long lines of data, but it's theoretical in the sense that there are obvious workarounds using actual text editors.

Comment: a tsv suggests that the data is tabular.  Why not just import it into sqlite (change the separator to tab with `.separator \t`) and then you can run `select * from artists sort by name` or whatever column you want.  Far more functionality would be available to you.